# How can i get data from my one node to another node file?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 node file, one node i called it `test.js` node, which is in root folder, now my another node js file in `functions/index.js`, i want to run my test node in my index.js file, here i have put my files code of that, can anyone please help me how to get its data ?

test.js (it is in root folder)

```
const GeotabApi = require('mg-api-js');
const authentication = {
    credentials: {
        database: '***',
        userName: '***',
        password: '***'
    }
}
const api = new GeotabApi(authentication);

api.call('Get', { typeName: 'Group', resultsLimit: 100 })
    .then(result => {
        return result;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return error;
    });
```

I want to call that test.js file to my index.js, i have put my code of index.js file but i am not getting its output

functions/index.js

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');

function runScript(scriptPath, callback) {

    // keep track of whether callback has been invoked to prevent multiple invocations
    var invoked = false;

    var process = childProcess.fork(scriptPath);

    // listen for errors as they may prevent the exit event from firing
    process.on('error', function (err) {
        if (invoked) return;
        invoked = true;
        callback(err);
    });

    // execute the callback once the process has finished running
    process.on('exit', function (code) {
        if (invoked) return;
        invoked = true;
        var err = code === 0 ? null : new Error('exit code ' + code);
        callback(err);
    });

}

exports.test_groups_list = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    runScript('../test.js', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.set({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }).send({ "status": 0,"msg":err });
        } else {
            res.set({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }).send({ "status": 1 });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What data do you need to get from `test.js` exactly? I think you can just export a function and require it in `functions/index.js`

Comment: i need result data from test.js file

Comment: I think you can use the node modules system for that. This is a short guide https://www.nodebeginner.org/blog/post/nodejs-tutorial-what-are-node.js-modules/ I doubt using `child_process` would work well on cloud functions